# Cluster tweet texts

Tags: python, clustering, twitter

I am using using the following code to cluster tweet texts. The input is a dictionary containing tweet-id and tweet text as key value pairs.

Example:

```
{'43543':'hello','984598':'how are you'}
```

and the expected output is

```
{0:[list of ids that have similar texts],1:[list of ids that have similar texts]}
```

The following code is working fine to generate clusters of similar texts for a small number of tweet id-text pairs but I am trying to cluster approx. 55000 tweets and even after running the code for 2 hours, I am not getting an output. Is the problem with my code or with my computer (2Ghz, 4GB RAM)?

```
import time
import os,sys
import itertools
import math
import argparse
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from hashlib import sha1
import random, struct
from random import sample,choice
from sklearn import metrics

def gen_shingles(text):
    a=text.split(" ")
    s=set()
    for i in range(len(a)-2):
        s.add(a[i]+" "+a[i+1]+" "+a[i+2])
    return s

def create_lsh(id_text_dict,no_of_perm,thr):
    M_PRIME = (1 << 89) - 1
    MAX_HASH = (1 << 64) - 1
    random.seed(427)
    A,B = np.array([(random.randint(1, M_PRIME),random.randint(0, 
    M_PRIME)) for _ in range(no_of_perm)]).T
    mycorpus=[(ids,gen_shingles(text)) for ids,text in 
    id_text_dict.items()]
    global hashcorp
    hashcorp=dict.fromkeys([tup[0] for tup in mycorpus])

    def get_permuted_hashes(token):
        hv=int(sha1(token.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(),16)% (10 ** 12)
        return np.bitwise_and((A * hv + B) % M_PRIME,MAX_HASH)

    def get_lsh(sig,nbands):
        for i,band in enumerate(np.array_split(sig,nbands)):
            return sha1(("ab" + str(band) + "ba"+str(i)).encode('utf8')).digest()


    def get_bandwidth(n, thr):
        best = n, 1
        minerr  = float("inf")
        for r in range(1, n + 1):
            try:
                b = 1. / (thr ** r)
            except: 
                return best
            err = abs(n - b * r)
            if err < minerr:
                best = r
                minerr = err
        return best

    for key,doc in mycorpus:
        hashvalues=np.empty(no_of_perm)
        hashvalues.fill(MAX_HASH)
        for token in doc:
            hashvalues=np.minimum(get_permuted_hashes(token), hashvalues)
        hashcorp[key]=hashvalues
    bandwidth=get_bandwidth(no_of_perm, thr)
    bands=int(math.ceil(float(no_of_perm)/float(bandwidth)))
    doc_to_lsh={}
    lsh_dict={}
    for key,m in hashcorp.items():
        signatures = [sig for sig in get_lsh(m,bands)]
        doc_to_lsh[key]=signatures
        for sig in signatures:
            if sig in lsh_dict:
                lsh_dict[sig].append(key)
            else:
                lsh_dict[sig]=[key]
    return lsh_dict,doc_to_lsh,hashcorp


def jaccard(h1,h2):
    return np.float(np.count_nonzero(h1==h2)) /np.float(h2.size)

def connected(seed,lshdict,doc2lsh,t):
    cluster=set([seed])
    base=set([seed])
    while len(base)>0:
        s=base.pop()
        candidates=set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([lshdict[sig] for 
sig in doc2lsh[s]]))
        m1=hashcorp[s]
        for cand in candidates:
            if cand in cluster:continue
                m2=hashcorp[cand]
            if jaccard(m1,m2) >=t:
                cluster.add(cand)
                base.add(cand)
    return cluster
def create_clusters(lsh_dict,doc_to_lsh,hashcorp,thr):
    doc2cluster={}
    count=0
    for doc in hashcorp:
        if doc not in doc2cluster:
            cl=connected(doc,lsh_dict,doc_to_lsh,thr)
            doc2cluster.update({i:count for i in cl })
            count+=1
    final={}
    for val in doc2cluster:
        if doc2cluster[val] in final:
            final[doc2cluster[val]].append(val)
        else:
            final[doc2cluster[val]]=[val]
    final_clusters={}
    for keys,values in final.items():
        if len(values)>=3:
            final_clusters.update({keys:values})
    return final_clusters
```

Comment: Does the code work as expected on, say, 100 tweets? Thanks.